# What's the name of this tool of Blender?

Tags: modeling, image

That tool/mode where you have a background image and you can start modeling things, create meshes and etc. using that image as reference? 
Also: Can ANY image be used in this mode/tool?

Comment: I guess you mean *fspy* right?

Comment: Hello :). Or it could be *Add > Image > Reference*

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no special mode for this. Once you have a background image added to the scene (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Image > Background*), create your first primitive in *Object Mode*, then switch to *Edit Mode* and start modifying and extruding your model based on the background image.

Answer (score 0):

***Note: This is for Blender 2.79***

I think the mode you mean would be `Edit Mode`. To insert a background image, press <kbd>N</kbd> then scroll down to `Background Image`. Expand the panel then click `Add Image`. Click `Open` and select your image file. Make sure the checkbox next to Background Image is ticked! And you can use any image, but make sure it is a compatible file format and that you have the rights to use the image.